# justify-content disappeared in real element

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
circleSet: {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  display: 'flex',
  width:'100%',
  height: '104px',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'spcace-between',
}
```

I am using react. I can see `justifyContent` in chrome with react tool, but it disappears in real element. Anyone knows what happened?

`justifyContent` in react
[image]

`justifyContent` disappear
[image]

Comment: because of typo,change to justifyContent : 'space-between'

Comment: Happens to best of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your css: `justifyContent: 'spcace-between'`.
It should be **space** not spcace.

Comment: thanks! I spent 2 hours on this....I will check my spelling first next time T_T